# Building Cython-compiled python code with PyInstaller

Tags: python, cython, pyinstaller

I am trying to build a Python multi-file code with `PyInstaller`. For that I have compiled the code with `Cython`, and am using `.so` files generated in place of `.py` files.

Assuming the 1st file is `main.py` and the imported ones are `file_a.py` and `file_b.py`, I get `file_a.so` and `file_b.so` after Cython compilation.

When I put `main.py`, `file_a.so` and `file_b.so` in a folder and run it by `"python main.py"`, it works.

But when I build it with `PyInstaller` and try to run the executable generated, it throws errors for imports done in `file_a` and `file_b`.

How can this be fixed? One solution is to import all standard modules in `main.py` and this works. But if I do not wish to change my code, what can be the solution?

Answer (score 30):

So I got this to work for you.

Please have a look at [Bundling Cython extensions with Pyinstaller](https://github.com/prologic/pyinstaller-cython-bundling)

**Quick Start:**

```
git clone https://github.com/prologic/pyinstaller-cython-bundling.git
cd pyinstaller-cython-bundling
./dist/build.sh
```

This produces a static binary:

```
$ du -h dist/hello
4.2M    dist/hello
$ ldd dist/hello
    not a dynamic executable
```

And produces the output:

```
$ ./dist/hello 
Hello World!
FooBar
```

---

Basically this came down to producing a simple `setup.py` that builds the extensions `file_a.so` and `file_b.so` and then uses [pyinstaller](http://pyinstaller.org) to bundle the application the extensions into a single executeble.

Example `setup.py`:

```
from glob import glob
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize


setup(
    name="test",
    scripts=glob("bin/*"),
    ext_modules=cythonize("lib/*.pyx")
)
```

Building the extensions:

```
$ python setup.py develop
```

Bundling the application:

```
$ pyinstaller -r file_a.so,dll,file_a.so -r file_b.so,dll,file_b.so -F ./bin/hello
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for putting it all together!

Comment: Yeah no worries at all! It was *quite* fun!

Comment: Is there a windows equivalent for this?   ./dist/build.sh are not recognised even with cygwin

Comment: 150mb/exe seems like way too big

Comment: Is this specific to Windows platform ? I saw in the docs that the -r flag is just for Windows, but you're bundling Unix .so files so I'm a bit confused

Comment: Hey, How can I add packaged that are imported in my source code? Your code is working fine. But it gives an error when outside modules are imported in the code.

Comment: I have faced this problem and sharing the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707869/build-cython-compiled-modules-and-python-code-into-executable-binary-using-pyins/55744155#55744155

May this will help too

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone's looking for a quick fix.

I ran into the same situation and found a quick/dirty way to do the job. The issue is that pyinstaller is not adding the necessary libraries in the .exe file that are needed to run your program.

All you need to do is import all the libraries (and the .so files) needed into your main.py file (the file which calls file_a.py and file_b.py). For example, assume that file_a.py uses opencv library (cv2) and file_b.py uses matplotlib library. Now in your main.py file you need to import cv2 and matplotlib as well. Basically, whatever you import in file_a.py and file_b.py, you have to import that in main.py as well. This tells pyinstaller that the program needed these libraries and it includes those libraries in the exe file.