# Compiling Cython to Executable including .pyd files

Tags: dependencies, executable, cython

I would like to create an executable from my converted python code (it is now .c files from cython) but include the .pyd files in the executable such that the program can be run alone in any directory. 
Is there any possible way? 
Thank you!

Comment: This may be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525861/building-cython-compiled-python-code-with-pyinstaller

Comment: Thank you. I did see that post, but I was hoping to do it without using PyInstaller.