# Utilising Cython with Pyinstaller

Tags: c, python-3.x, cython, pyinstaller

I am trying to build a program in python using Cython and PyInstaller. Before starting, I built this test program. However, the two modules aren't working together at all. I have tried them both separately, and they work.
I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525861/building-cython-compiled-python-code-with-pyinstaller) but that doesn't work.

I also tried using cython to compile it to c and then use gcc, but that doesn't work either (I added the python.h file, and gcc just aborts after complaining that the keyword doesn't exist)

```py
#hello.pyx 
import pygame
def say_hello_to(name):
    print("Hello %s!" % name)
```

```py
#hello.py
from hello import say_hello_to
say_hello_to('Me')
```

```py
#setup.py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
     name='Hello world app',
     ext_modules=cythonize("hello.pyx"),
     zip_safe=False,
)
```

All of this works in CPython, with :

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Then

```
python3 hello.py
```

But `PyInstaller` keeps complaining it can't find the module hello. I tried add-data and add-binaries, as well as editing the spec file, and it still doesn't work, saying:

```
invalid add_data_or_binary value: 'home:Achyut-BK:hello.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
```

Comment: For a start the two modules have __exactly the same name__ as far as Python is concerned

Comment: @ DavidW I tried executing the so file created by the setup script, if that's what you mean i got a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. If you meant something else, please excuse me, this is my first time doing cython

Comment: That is not what I mean. What I mean is that calling one file `hello.pyx / .so` and another file `hello.py` is going to confuse Python. How does the line `from hello import say_hello_to` know which one to use?

Comment: @DavidW hello.py is the main, that imports hello(the so file), so, since hello.py can't be called, it calls the shared object. Also, this works with CPython3 but not PyInstaller

Comment: Right, well I'd suggest that this naming arrangement is confusing PyInstaller. I've said everything I plan to here so I won't reply further.

Comment: Got the solution. The trick is to use the --hidden-import= command option

Comment: Aside from that, in the hello.py, change `from setuptools import setup` to `from distutils.core import setup`