# How to compile python script importing modules to executable using cython

Tags: python, cython, python-3.7, cythonize

Maybe this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find an answer for this particular situation: I want to compile and distribute my python Code to c and then to a binary using gcc. For distribution, I use appimagetool to include libraries.

I use the command

`cython3 -3 myapp.py --embed`

to create the C code, and then

`gcc myapp.c -o myapp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags python3)`

to generate the executable. This works, but when I transfer the executable to another machine, I get the error

`No Module named AnyRandomModule`

Where AnyRandomModule is a python module I am importing. When I install it via

`pip3 install AnyRandomModule`

it works. But I don't want that the user needs to install the libs himself. How can I bundle my imported python modules in my executable, or otherwise compile them to .so shared library files from which I can import? I already tried to convert them to .so files using the quick start example from the Cython documentation, but I still get the same error when executing the myapp executable, even though those .so files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this answer:
[Building Cython-compiled python code with PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525861/building-cython-compiled-python-code-with-pyinstaller)

to bundle everything together (use cython and then pack everything using pyinstaller which should pack all the packages)

Comment: I don't want to use Pyinstaller, should have mentioned that. I have a working Pyinstaller setup but I don't want to use it this time because it makes decompilation trivial.

Comment: Looked at it more intensely... thanks, you pointed me to the right solution. Pyinstaller files are easily decompiled, but if I compile my module as a shared object with cython this bytecode is quite safe. Thanks!